# Opposite of last() function

Tags: php, dom, xpath

What is the opposite of XPath's `last()` function, to select the "first" (apparently, there is no `first()`) result from query?

Or, how would I mimic it?

#### Update

Maybe the problem is with my specific example using ancestors and context.

**document.html**

```
<div id="holder" special-header="We have a special header here">
    <div class="element" special-header="And this is even more specific">
        <p id="interested">Content, content</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**script.php**

```
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->loadHTMLFile('document.html');
$contextNode = $document->getElementById('interested');

/* first try */
$first = $xpath->query('//ancestor::*[@special-header][1]', $contextNode);
echo $first->getAttribute('special-header'); // result == "We have a special header here" intended == "And this is even more specific"

/* second try */
$one = $xpath->query('//ancestor::*[@special-header][last()]', $contextNode); // in case it starts from "first found ancestor" and descends
echo $one->getAttribute('special-header'); // same result as before..
```

Trying with `position()=1` I get the same result again.

Comment: Question has been updated to reflect my environment.

Comment: Answer has been updated to reflect your environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the meaning of the expression `//ancestor::*[@special-header]` is rather vague, because `//` forces searching from the root node.

The solution is to remove the `//` at the beginning of the expressions.

BTW, your code is actually not working =). Here is the corrected version:

```
$html = <<<HTML
<div id="holder" special-header="We have a special header here">
    <div class="element" special-header="And this is even more specific">
        <p id="interested">Content, content</p>
    </div>
</div>
HTML;

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);
$contextNode = $doc->getElementById('interested');
$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);

$first = $xpath->query('ancestor::*[@special-header][1]',
                       $contextNode) -> item(0);
echo $first->getAttribute('special-header') . "\n";

$one = $xpath->query('ancestor::*[@special-header][last()]',
                     $contextNode)-> item(0);
echo $one->getAttribute('special-header') . "\n";
```

Results in:

```
C:\>\php\php.exe dom_games.php
And this is even more specific
We have a special header here
```

Comment: About the code not working, could be, I didn't want to put a lot of effort and better work on getting a solution up, so I made a quick "environment", but I think it resembled the idea. But for now I'm working with getting all ancestors, and `$first = $xpathresult->item($xpathresult->length - 1);`.

Comment: @tom, I updated the answer. the solution is to remove `//` at the beginning of the xpath expressions.

Comment: Lower reputation, in-depth description is higher priority when accepting an answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Would it be strange to suggest `1`?

**EDIT**: remove the `//` leader in your code.

Answer (score 2):

Well the first item is always the one selected with the position `1` so you don't need a function for that, you can simply do e.g. `foo[1]` or `//bar[1]`.

Comment: Actually, in the general case `//bar[1]` selects more than one element. I believe you know this fact well -- this is one of the most FAQ (after default namespace related questions) in XPath.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `1` as the index of the first result. The point of `last()` is so you can select the last index from a variable number of indexes. But the first index is always `1`.